# Dotnet run command always runs the same code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I apologize in advance if my question seems confusing, I've just started learning C# so I don't know much about it.

so I'm learning to code In C# with Visual studio Code as my IDE. I Followed [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/with-visual-studio-code?pivots=dotnet-6-0) to help in setting up C# on visual studio code.

but I've encountered a problem, normally when I used to want to make a python program, I just make a new file with the python extension and it runs just fine, but this isn't the case in C#. when I followed the tutorial I got a simple hello world program.

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
```

but then If I want to make a new program I created a new file with the .cs extension in the same folder and wrote a different code in it. but when I wanted to run it using the Dotnet run command in the terminal as I've been taught. it always runs the previous program and gives me that as an output, rather than the newer one. I tried changing the words after the namespace and tried changing the class and also the main function, but it always seems to run the older code. this might just be due to my lack of knowledge but I tried looking it up and found no answer. how could I run the newer program rather than the previous one? if that's even possible?

edit: i've been informed to Add more details and screenshots

[This is how my folder looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YC2MS.png)

the program named "Program.cs" is the the first one that runs a hello world program and the one named "Thinking with strings.cs" has this code

```
namespace Code
{
    class Program
    {
        static void main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hello\nworld");
        }
    }
}
```

the output like said is
Hello, World! rather than,

hello
world

I also tried deleting the program.cs file but what would happen is it tries to run the code.csproj file which contains this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

and of course this is HTML and therefore it would fail so no luck there.

Comment: The entry point for python is file, and in .NET files are built into assemblies (.exe or .dll files). Entry point for assembly is "main" function. So you either need to modify your "main" function to execute new code or create different project to have different "main" in it

Comment: hmm I think I get what you mean, for C# it starts off at a different point and thinks of it as the whole thing? and for main function, Do you mean this "static void main(string[] args)" if so I also tried changing main into something and the same issue persisted

Comment: You got the point. Regarding your case, this might be caused by multiple issues - you have not saved the file or you execute dotnet run from different folder. some more details, screenshots are needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was just thinking of it in a wrong way, and making a new file with the .cs extension just doesn't work. a good way for me is just to make a new folder and run the "dotnet new console" command on there which works like normal. but thinking of each file on its own is the wrong perspective when it comes to C#. thanks for the help "user7313094"

Answer (score 0):

if you go to the Properties of the project (project -> right click -> properties), you'll see the details of the project including the main entry point.
Observe it and you probably get your answer.

there's another thing as well, see the two drop down right before the PLAY b[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZzJY.png)utton. you'll know what i mean.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XF23b.png)

Comment: I apologize could you Elaborate more? I'm not finding where to access the properties of my project in visual or the the two drop downs right before the play button.  maybe the new details I provided could be helpful?

Comment: add two Screenshots. do let me know if it helps you

Comment: im new to this platform. so pardon me for the un-structured way

Comment: you seem to be using visual studio, I'm using visual studio code which is different in many ways so sadly, its not helpful. appreciate it though

Comment: it is indeed hard to enjoy c# through VS Code as it's light weight. and Our C# as you know is a Heavy Lifter. it surely need something on that level. of course you can enjoy programming in VS Code. FOR NOW (Trust me, i've been there, you will shift to VS yourself after some deep knowledge)

Comment: find something called 'StartupObject' in the properties or app.config, or create one and put your core class there which you wanna run

Comment: Thanks for the advice! it definitely seems to be heading that way, visual studio code is just what I've been using for a long while and it works just great with HTML, and python. but I definitely see how its a hassle for C# and I assume it wouldn't do so well with lower-level languages either so mayhap ill use both for now. and sticking to visual studio for C#.